# Javascript: How do I refresh text values

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function balanceRefresher() {
    <b>Balance: 
    document.write(playerBalance)
    </b>
    }
setInterval(balanceRefresher, 1000);
</script>
```

Obviously, this isn't actual code, but what I'm trying to do is refresh variable 'playerBalance' in text. I have no idea what other way I could do this in, as I am an almost complete beginner to javascript.

Comment: Assuming the snippet is a pseudo-code only, still getting familiar with [the method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) you use is always useful.

Comment: You seem to have some things mixed here. Your refresher will do nothing, except for throwing an error (unless you are using jsx, however that will still result to nothing). Where do you want to save the changes in the balance? from where should it come?

Comment: You should try to learn to use `document.getElement...` methods and how to manage the DOM, this question is a bit too basic IMHO. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dom/2584/getting-started-with-dom/14126/html-markup#t=201708180847512850282

Answer (score 0):

document.write, does as the name suggests writes to the document, if you want to dynamically modify and element on the display then create a placeholder and then access the element and modify, for example, in your document create a placeholder:

```
    <div id="any_id"></div>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
    let el = document.getElementByID("any_id");

    if ( el ) {
        if ( el.hasChildNodes() ) {
            el.removeChild(el.childNodes[0]);
        }
        el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("your text"));
    }
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

Answer (score 0):

look this example [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/77c75w7u/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var i=1;
setInterval(function(){
$('p').html('');
$('p').append('<span id="add_here">'+i+'</span>'); 
i++;
}, 1000);
});
```